# Can I get the probability of a value being 0.5 larger or smaller?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, discrete-data

So I have some clothing data, with some body measurements and the sizing. The sizing is a discrete variable ranging from 7 to 14 with steps of 0.5. 
I know that a specific consumer with specific measurements has a probability of 65% picking size 10. How can I know the probability of him picking a size that's 0.5 larger (10.5) or 0.5 smaller (9.5)?

EDIT: for clarification, let's say Y is the size, and X the variable of the body measurements. Y is approximated to a normal distribution $N(11, 1.02)$. In this case, just to make sure I interpreted the question right, isn't the question about the conditional probability $P(|Y-10|=0.5  / X = X\_spec )$  with $X\_spec$ being the given measurement values of the customer ?

Comment: This cannot be answered without more information on the distribution of the RV.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is the size picked by the consumer, you are trying to find $P(|X-10| = 0.5)$. If you have data, a raw estimate would be to create a new variable $y = |x-10|$ and count how many of your observations have $y = 0.5$.

However, if you don't have data and the only thing you know about $X$ is that $P(X = 10) = 0.65$, there is no direct way to find $P(|X-10| = 0.5)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but then, the customer has a specific given set of measurements, isn't it more a conditional probability?

Comment: @JamesGot How so? $P(\vert X - 10\vert = 0.5 \bigg{\vert} X = 10)$?

Comment: No. never mind though. I was thinking of something too complicated, I ended up solving this with prediction intervals from a regression. Thanks :)